# why bash modifies the content of my variable

Tags: bash, macos

consider this code, on Mac :

```
#/bin/bash
x="-map [audioWithGain]"
echo $x
echo "-map [audioWithGain]"
```

Output on a Mac 12.7 is

```
-map t
-map [audioWithGain]
```

Why, oh why? Perfectly work on linux of course.

Any idea for workarounds?
I tried all sorts of

```
x="-map"" "'[audioWithGain]'
```

and such, to no avail!

but this works: (!)

```
x="-map [hGain]"
```

Comment: Also see [Bash Pitfalls #14 (echo $foo)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo).

Comment: `echo $x` is broken.  (In fact, unquoted `$x` is usually broken.)  `echo "$x"` is better, but still broken because of peculiarities of the `echo` command.  `printf '%s\n' "$x"` is good.  See the accepted, and excellent, answer to [Why is printf better than echo?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/65803/264812).

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several problems with the code.  The report that it produces includes links to more information about the problems and how to fix them.  It's a good idea to run [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) on all new and modified shell code.

Comment: The answer by choroba explains how to fix this. Aside from this, you could also consider writing your shell scripts in zsh instead of bash, where you wouldn't face this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[audioWithGain]` is interpreted as a character class and matched. There's a file or directory named `t` which matches it.

That's because variable expansion happens before pathname expansion (see EXPANSION in `man bash`).

Double quote the variable to prevent it:

```
echo "$x"
```

Otherwise, what bash runs is

```
echo -map [audioWithGain]
```